# How to store Autocomplete Material- UI values and names in array in spread operator hooks

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ DEPARTMENT: " ", Hosp_Name: " ", Equip_Name: " ", Status: " ",
Equip_Id: " " });

const handleChange = (event,value ) => {
setFilter({...filter,[event.name]: value.value });

console.log(filter)

return (

```
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      name="DEPARTMENT"
      options={dept} 
      options={dept.map(option => (  option.DEPARTMENT? option.DEPARTMENT:'' ))}        
      value={option.DEPARTMENT}
      sx={{ width: 200 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Equip" />}      
      onChange = {handleChange}
     
    />       
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={equip.map((option) => (option.EQUIPMENT_NAME))} 
      name="Equip_Name"        
      sx={{ width: 200 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Equip" />}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"        
      name="Hosp_Name" 
      options={hospname.map((option) => (option.Unit_Name)? option.Unit_Name:'' )}  
      sx={{ width: 150 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Hosp" />}
      onChange={handleChange}

    />
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"          
      name="Status" 
      options={status.map((option) => (option.EQUIP_STATUS)? option.EQUIP_STATUS:'')}  
      sx={{ width: 150 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Status" />}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"         
      name="Equip_Id" 
      options={equipid.map((option) => (option.EQUIPMENT_ID)? option.EQUIPMENT_ID:'')}  
      sx={{ width: 150 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="ID" />}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

I want to store name and value in  setFilter({...filter,[event.name]: value.value });
console.log(filter) should show data from auto coplete as [DEPARTMENT=ccu&Equip_Name=Cardiac monitor&Hosp_Name=Beas Hosp) ....and so on]
and use to query api like this [http://192.168.16.118:4000/equipments?search=${filter}](http://192.168.16.118:4000/equipments?search=$%7Bfilter%7D)

to get the value from node js express